# What is the quotient group $G/R(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group, simple-groups, solvable-groups

The maximal solvable normal subgroup of $G$ is called the radical subgroup of $G$, and it is denoted by $Rad(G)$ of $R(G)$.

**Question:** Is the quotient group $G/R(G)$ been classified (i.e., it always has some well-known group structure)?  [Here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_group) it is mentioned that $G/R(G)$ is semi-simple. What does that mean?

Edit: I thought that semi-simple groups are the product of simple groups. Thus I got confused with this.

Comment: The link is about Lie groups, not discrete groups.

Comment: A Lie group is *semisimple*, if and only if its Lie algebra is *semisimple*, i.e., is a direct sum of simple Lie algebras, and simple here means without proper, nontrivial ideals. See [your link, part II](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lie_group,_semi-simple).